# Can I host lichess server to my local machine to use the study offline?

Tags: engines, analysis, software, study, lichess

[Lichess](https://lichess.org) is a free, Ad-free and [Open-Source](https://lichess.org/source) chess server. To me, it has the best **STUDY** option over the internet. I am thinking whether it's possible or not to host a localhost setup using the source code of lichess into my PC. The sole reason is to use it for studying the game.

Since [*Stockfish.js*](https://github.com/nmrugg/stockfish.js/) is available, I am thinking to retain the web layout.

By the way, I have tried [**Scid Vs PC**](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/) with the free database, provided by Lichess, but its UI and UX is not at all refined. So, my question is,

"**Has anyone tried to host Lichess to their local machine, that ran smoothly offline? If not, is it possible to do so ?**"

Comment: I have not installed it myself, but they have a GitHub Page (https://github.com/ornicar/lila) with Installation Instructions (https://github.com/ornicar/lila/wiki/Lichess-Development-Onboarding). This may be a good place to start. They also mention a Discord-Server on their GitHub page - which might be the best way to get help from the people who are directly associated with the development of lichess! :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have joined discord today. Digging further into the topic, via the following channel: https://discord.com/channels/280713822073913354/693123750845218836
Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Were you successful at this? Would be awesome to have a simple docker image available that anyone could just run.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I did it a little while ago. It's of course possible. You will need to be technical capable of doing it as it won't be like a one-click installer.

Comment: Did you follow the installation manuals on GitHub? Actually I am facing problems in the web sockets after switching in the windows from Linux :(.

Answer (score 0):

> "Has anyone tried to host Lichess to their local machine, that ran
> smoothly offline? If not, is it possible to do so ?"

I was asked to do such a thing a couple of years ago as a paid project. I'm retired and really have no interest in doing paid work so I handed on the idea to one of my sons who is a young and very enthusiastic software engineer.

He had a look at this but what put him off was that it uses a strange programming language (Scala?) and the non-relational database MongoDB. He happily installed the programming language and had a play but baulked at MongoDB. He ended up declining the project as what was being offered came nowhere near matching the amount of work involved according to his estimation.

If you seriously want to pursue this then [this github page](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/wiki/Lichess-Development-Onboarding) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have already visited the page, you have mentioned. I do agree with you, that PostgreSQL would be better than MongoDB. I have installed Lila successfully. But I faced some problems regarding the WebSockets. I have joined their discord server today. Hope I can fix those issues.
Thanks again for your help sir. Have a great day :)

Comment: Strange=>opinion; it’s really not all that strange :)